# searching a value in 2 columns jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have been trying to search a value between 2 columns by using this code

```
  timelapse_table.columns([3,4]).every ->
    that = this
    $("#camera-name").on "keyup change", ->
      that.search( @value ).draw()
```

but this only search for column 3 not 4. I want to make it as if value ABC either in column 3 or column 4 it should show the results.
`$("#camera-name")` is my input for search. and `timelapse_table = $("#timelapse_datatables").DataTable`
Any help will be appreciated thanks